# jQuery Plugin for trasforming img tab to links

Tags: jquery, linker

I found linker.js " http://www.jquery.gr/linker " and it can make 
http://www.example.com to

```
[a href="http://www.example.com" >http://www.example.com</a]
```

But now i need like this : 
example -

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" class="lightbox" />
```

to -

```
<a href="myimage.jpg" rel="lightbox" ><img src="myimage.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
```

i want to auto embed my img tag with a tag.
Is this possilbe with linker.js ?

Thank you .

Comment: i think it is possible wihtout any plugins required... but yes!! you need to clearify your questiona bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michal Klouda beat me to it, but:

hm..Not sure about your plugin, but what's to stop you from doing this:

```
$("img.lightbox").wrap(function() {
    return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" rel="lightbox" />';
});
```

also if you add it in the `<head>` tags you need to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.lightbox").wrap(function() {
         return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" rel="lightbox" />';
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks Michal, but if you wanted to make it work better you could do a '$(this).attr('rel')' instead of defining Lightbox or add a class so it doesn't do that to all your Lightbox images

Comment: where are you adding the code? if you are just throwing it in the <head> tag then you have to wrap the entire thin in a $.ready() function(see edit).

Answer (score 1):

## **HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="myimage.jpg" class="lightbox" />
</div>
```

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lightbox').each(function(){
        this1 = $(this);
        this1.parent().prepend('<a href="'+this1.attr('src') +'" rel="lightbox"> <img src="'+ this1.attr('src')+'"class="lightbox"/></a>');
       this1.remove();
    });
});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/FK8Vu/